# How to add Linux format time output

Tags: linux, bash, time

I am running this command:

```
showjobs -u rsingh70 -n 365 | grep CPUTime
```

And I am getting this output:

```
CPUTime           : 00:00:05
CPUTime           : 00:00:12
CPUTime           : 00:00:01
CPUTime           : 6:12:48:54
CPUTime           : 37:10:39:36
CPUTime           : 05:05:33
CPUTime           : 2:08:49:34
CPUTime           : 61:22:05:34
CPUTime           : 28:16:43:32
CPUTime           : 49:23:58:05
CPUTime           : 02:38:39
CPUTime           : 00:37:00
CPUTime           : 00:37:00
CPUTime           : 00:46:01
CPUTime           : 35:04:10:36
CPUTime           : 00:00:13
CPUTime           : 00:00:12
CPUTime           : 33:16:39:11
CPUTime           : 4:06:10:13
CPUTime           : 00:36:04
CPUTime           : 00:01:08
CPUTime           : 30:01:37:30
CPUTime           : 2:16:48:37
```

How do I add up all these times, so that I get output which is summation of all these recorded times?

Comment: does `showjobs` have an option to format the time or simply output the sum for you?

Comment: @anikaM I'm assuming this `61:22:05:34` means 61 days 22 hours 5 minutes 34 seconds. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that timestamps are

```
HH:MM:SS[:MILLISEC]
```

You should definitely explain the spec of your timestamps as required by Ed and us.

##### With `bash`

```
#!/bin/bash

timestamps=( $(
    showjobs -u rsingh70 -n 365 |
        awk '/CPUTime/{print $NF}'
))

for timestamp in "${timestamps[@]}"; do
    IFS=: read -ra a <<< "$timestamp"
    if ((${#a[@]} == 4)); then
        ((seconds+=10#${a[0]}*3600+10#${a[1]}*60+10#${a[2]}+10#${a[3]}/1000))
    else
        ((seconds+=10#${a[0]}*3600+10#${a[1]}*60+10#${a[2]}))
    fi
done

days=$((seconds/86400))
hours=$((seconds/3600%24))
minutes=$((seconds/60%60))
seconds=$((seconds%60))
echo "Total time is $days days $hours hours $minutes minutes $seconds secondes"
```

##### With `awk`

Re-using/borrowing `END` part of the elegant code from Glenn

```
showjobs -u rsingh70 -n 365 | awk '
    /CPUTime/ {
        split($NF, a, ":")
        if (NF == 5) {
            seconds+=a[1]*3600+a[2]*60+a[3]+a[4]/1000
        }
        else {
            seconds+=a[1]*3600+a[2]*60+a[3]
        }
    }
    END {
        s = seconds % 60; mins = (seconds - s)/60
        m = mins % 60; hrs = (mins - m)/60
        h = hrs % 24
        days = (hrs - h)/24
        printf "%d days %02d hours %02d minutes %02d seconds\n", days, h, m, s
  }
'
```

##### Output

```
12 days 11 hours 42 minutes 34 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
showjobs -u rsingh70 -n 365 | awk -F: '
  /CPUTime/ {seconds += $NF + 60*$(NF-1) + 3600*$(NF-2) + 86400*$(NF-3)}
  END {
    s = seconds % 60; mins = (seconds - s)/60
    m = mins % 60; hrs = (mins - m)/60
    h = hrs % 24; days = (hrs - h)/24
    printf "%d:%02d:%02d:%02d\n", days, h, m, s
  }
'
```

```
293:06:53:30
```

Comment: How do you handle cases where there's 4 columns or 3? Could be `33:16:39:11` (4 cols) or `00:00:13` (3 cols).

Comment: Not sure this can be working, see this debug: https://hastebin.com/share/eqerewevoj.swift

Comment: OK, just plain wrong. Borrowed part of your code in my answer

Comment: My answer is "just plain wrong"? Not so. For colon separated records where there are 4 columns ($1 == "CPUTime  "), the _numeric value_ of $(NF-3) (i.e. the number of days) is zero. There is no reason to have separate logic for 4 columns vs 5)

Comment: Why we have completely different outputs?

Comment: Why are you dividing by 1000?

Comment: I'm assuming this `61:22:05:34` means 61 days 22 hours 5 minutes 34 seconds. Am I wrong?

Comment: OP didn't explain how the timestamp are defined. Last col could be milliseconds. But, yes, makes sense, but we don't have this pattern

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to keep multiplying them by 60 and 3600 along the way. Just sum up the individual components, then do the time math once in the end :

```
12 days : 11 hrs : 42 mins : 34.322 secs
```

> 

```
    # gawk profile, created Tue Apr 25 10:27:54 2023
    BEGIN {
     1      ____ = length(FS = "^.+ |" (OFS = ":"))
     1       ___ = split(substr(______ = "1000",
                          index(______,_ = _<_))_, __, "")
    }
    23  NF { NF = ____
    92       for (_ = ___;_;_--)
                 __[_] += $(NF - _)
         }
    END {
     1      OFS = " : "
     1       ____ = -(_=___) + _^--_
     1      _____ =  _^_ - _-- * --_

     1      __[_] = (___ = __[_] /= ______) % _
     1       ++_
     1      __[_] = (___ = __[_] + int(___/____)) % ____
     1       ++_
     1      __[_] = (___ = __[_] + int(___/____)) % ____
     1       ++_
     1      __[_] = (___ = __[_] + int(___/____)) % _____

     1      print int(___ / _____) " days", __[(_)]  " hrs" ,
                                            __[--_]  " mins", 
                         sprintf("%d.%.3d", __[--_],
                                   ______ * __[--_]) " secs"
    }
```

> 

or in its condensed form :

```
printf("%.0s %d days : %d hrs : %d mins : %d.%.3d secs\n",
    (____ =  -(_ = ___) + _^--_) (_____ =_^_ - _-- * --_)\
   (__[_] = (___ = __[_] /= ______) % _)         ^!++_ \
   (__[_] = (___ = __[_] + int(___ /____)) % ____)^!++_ \
   (__[_] = (___ = __[_] + int(___/ ____)) % ____) ^!++_ \
   (__[_] = (___ = __[_] + int(___ /____)) % _____) ^!_,
                           int(___/_____), __[_], __[--_], __[--_],
                                                  ______ * __[--_])
```

Comment: Obfuscated `awk` way? =) Looks funny, but how it's relevant to name variables with `_`?

Comment: @GillesQuénot : you know what's actually funny ? doing absolutely unnecessary work like `a[3]*1` when it's already part of a summation command chain

Comment: @GillesQuénot : as for why underscores ? streamlined code like this ::::::::::::::: :::: ::::::::::::::::::::::: `function init_NaN_INF(_) { return CONST_negNAN =_= -(CONST_posNAN =_-= CONST_posINF =_= -(CONST_negINF =_= log(_<_))) }` ::::::: :::::::::::::::::: ::::::::::::  ::::::::::::::: numerically defining the 4 edge states of `IEEE 754` floating point using just 1 single temp variable

Comment: @GillesQuénot : or even better : `function ___(__, _) { return (__ *= _^=_<_) >= ++_^++_ * ++_^_ ? _-(__ < _^(_+_)) : -(_^_-- > --_*__) + _ }` :::::::: ignoring the surrogate range exclusions for a minute, this code alone is all you need to get back `# of UTF-8 bytes` by feeding in the decimal integer form of any unicode code point at the first argument (`__`) …. all without having to hard-code anything  - every comparison offset is dynamically generated on the fly, and only need 1 extra temp variable on top of the essential one to accept function input